# Closing the Handler, removing callbacks, cannot kill Activity

Tags: android, android-handler

In this activity I use `Runnable` to spin an image while the `Button` is pressed. 
The problem is that after I terminate whole app, this activity is brought upfront when I start my app again. I learned that this happens when callbacks are being removed incorrectly.

**My question**: How can I fix this code to remove all callbacks properly and avoid reopening the activity in wrong moment.

```
public class MatchTimeActivity extends Activity {

Button MatchTime;
TextView Header1;
ImageView Face;
Timer myTimer;
private Handler matchHandler;
private Runnable matchAction;
public final static String match_int_value1="com.planis.matchthetime.match_int_value1";
public final static String match_int_value2="com.planis.matchthetime.match_int_value2";

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_time);
    MatchTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MatchTimeButton);
    Header1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MatchTimeHeader);
    Typeface custom_font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font1.ttf");
    MatchTime.setTypeface(custom_font2);
    Header1.setTypeface(custom_font2);

    matchHandler = new Handler();
    matchAction = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Face = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MatchTimeImage);
            Face.setRotation(Face.getRotation()+9);                     
            matchHandler.postDelayed(this, 25);
        }
    };

    ListenTo(); 

}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}
public void ListenTo(){
    MatchTime.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        long time_start=0;
        long time_end=0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {                
                time_start=System.currentTimeMillis();
                matchHandler.post(matchAction);

                return true;
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {                  
                time_end=System.currentTimeMillis();
                long TimeCounted=time_end-time_start;
                matchHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                matchHandler = null;
                SaveAndSend(TimeCounted);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
}



public void SaveAndSend(long TimeCountedlong){
    int TimeCountedint=(int)(long) TimeCountedlong;
    Intent intent = getIntent();                                            
    int TimeToMatchsas = intent.getIntExtra("display_int_value",0);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ResultsActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("match_int_value1", TimeToMatchsas);
        intent2.putExtra("match_int_value2", TimeCountedint);
    startActivity(intent2);
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Are there other activities in your app? From the looks of your code when you start your app if this activity is the main activity in your manifest onCreate would be called which just creates a new handler and runnable. So are you looking for your app to start without launching this activity? When you say terminate the app are you switching to a different app so this app is still on the back stack? Just looking for more clarification.

Comment: This is not a main activity. In my main activity I override onBackPressed method with finish() to close an app. However during tests when I press Back button, app won't close and this activity goes upfront unnecessarily. When I press Home button and leave my app, this activity is brought upfront instead of main activity when I open it again. Sometimes on a second try everything works OK and app closes after pressing Back button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hook `onPause()` and cleanup your callbacks before your Activity is paused and ultimately destroyed.

`@Override
public void onPause() {
    matchHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    super.onPause();
}`